# Cant save a appointment in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Right now I can delete my appointment but can't save it.

This is my delete function :

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $appointment = Appointment::find($id);    
    $appointment->delete();

    return redirect( '/appointments' );
}
```

And this is my save function

```
public function update($id)
{
    $save_appointment = Appointment::find($id);
    $save_appointment->save();

    return redirect('/appointments');
}
```

For some reason it's not updating. The `id` is 100% correct. What am I doing wrong. Is it because I have in my Appointment `model` this :

```
protected $fillable = [
    'gender', 'options', 'user_id',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
```

Comment: what are you updating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function should be like this:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
    $save_appointment = Appointment::find($id);
    $save_appointment->update($request->all());
    $save_appointment->save();

    return redirect('/appointments');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing something really important, the whole information to update.

Let's talk in code:

```
public function update(Request $request) {
    $save_appointment = Appointment::find($request->id);
    $save_appointment->gender = $request->gender;
    $save_appointment->options = $request->options;
    $save_appointment->user_id = $request->user_id;
    $save_appointment->save();

    return redirect('/appointments'); }
```

Comment: No I created the appointment like this : `$tasks = Appointment::create($request->all());` is it possible to update it like that? I dont want to code it like that because it becomes huge when your form got 20 questions.

Comment: Yes, you can, check it and If you've any issue paste your code here.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Zloter gave me the answer :)